# How do I stop water from seeping between my porch roof and house siding?

Tags: leak, exterior, moisture

I have a small roof over my side door on my porch. Whenever it rains or snows, some water always seeps in between the small roof and the vinyl siding. It drips down the siding and makes a puddle on the porch. How can I prevent this? I assume there's a small gap that the water goes into, can I use something to seal it?

[image: Water seepage]

Comment: Do you have any photos from higher up or above. Specifically the roof/wall intersection flashing and gutter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to bet you need kick-out (rain diverter) flashing to divert the water off the roof and into the gutter at the point where the roof/wall intersection ends. It is probably the most left-out piece of flashing and causes lots of problems.

[image: Kickout Flashing] -*kick-out flashing*

[image: More Kick-out flashing]

However, there is no way to tell where the leak is coming from without a thorough inspection of the area. First step would be to check the roof/wall intersection above for proper flashing.

Answer (score 0):

Water leaks almost always originate higher up from where they come out.

I would suspect the flashing/ counter flashing along the roof line with the house.

Likely you will have to remove a several foot strip of siding to inspect what measures have been used to waterproof the house-roof junction.

Here is a thorough discussion of the theory and practice of [drainage planes by Building Sciences](http://www.buildingscience.com/documents/digests/bsd-105-understanding-drainage-planes).